# Running a cron job at 08:00 AM and 17:00 everyday

Tags: php

Hi I was trying different things here:
https://crontab.guru/
My idea was to set the cron job to run at 08:00 AM  and 17:00 everyday
But i couldn't made this to work. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried, what is "not working"...

Comment: set two different cron jobs instead for `00 17 * * *"` and `00 08 * * *` each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use commas to add multiple of that unit. This works for all time units, not just for hours:

`0 8,17 * * *`